# Using the inversion formula of a Fourier Transform to calculate a limit

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1-|x|/2 \quad \text{if} \ |x|\leq 2, \\ 0 \qquad \quad\quad\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Calculate the fourier transform of $f$ and hence, using inversion formula, show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (t)}{t^2}dt =2\pi.$$
I computed the fourier transform to be
$$
\hat{f}(t) = \frac{1-\cos(2t)}{t^2} = \frac{2\sin^2(t)}{t^2}.
$$
I'm not sure how to use it now. I thought that the inversion would give us our old function $f$ back... let alone a constant value.

The definition of the inversion formula is
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}dt.$$

Comment: Just take $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inversion formula give you :
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad f(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}(t)e^{ixt}\mathrm{d}t =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2}e^{ixt}\mathrm{d}t$$
Hence, 
$$ f(0) =1=  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t$$
So
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t = \pi .$$

It appears that there is not $2$ if your Fourier transform is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please double check my Fourier Transform? I used http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-2+to+0+of+(1%2Bx%2F2)*e%5E(-i*x*a)dx+%2B+integral+from+0+to+2+of+(1-x%2F2)*e%5E(-i*x*a)dx  
to compute my integral and it seems to get what I got...  
The definition the fourier transform given is  $$\hat{f}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ixt}dx$$

Comment: I've checked and your Fourier Transform is correct. The answer of $\int_\mathbb{R}\sin^2(t)/t^2 dt$ is $\pi$ (I've checked it with maple).